# export first instance of database to the second instance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a project in ruby on rails 3.0.I have a database schema in pg. I have the instance of this project on 2 servers with respective databases.Now I have to shift everything to one server.So how do I export data from one database to the other?It can not be a literal export-import of databases bcos it has many tables with id and many to many relationships.So basically I need to append it so that there s no conflict for example

```
Databse 1 table 1 user
id Name
1  Josh
2  Rajn 
4  Kush

Database  table 1 user
id Name
1  Ram
2  Kevin
7  Don
```

So the new should be

```
Databse  table 1 user
id Name
1  Ram
2  Kevin
7  Don
8  Josh
9  Rajn 
10 Kush
```

and the join tables should have the new ids too

Answer (score 2):

Not down the maximum value of the id field from all the target tables and add them as the offset values to the source id fields.

Ex:

**migration.sql**

```
SELECT @max_user_id := MAX(id) FROM users;
SELECT @max_comment_id := MAX(id) FROM comments;


# Then perform the following mysql commands in the target database:

INSERT INTO target.users(id, name) SELECT id + @max_user_id, name FROM source.users

INSERT INTO target.comments(id, comment, user_id) SELECT id + @max_comment_id, comment, user_id + @max_user_id FROM source.comments
```

Note that you cannot do the migration in

Comment: But it has many to many relationship to which need to the shifted also

Comment: Yatish, you should better try to write ruby code that handles all those relationships & stuff. Solution by @Arun is good & can be applied if you have limited tables with less complex relationships, but you have take care of those ids everywhere.